# What is the chance of getting a Bob-omb or a Mr. Saturn instead of a Turnip?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I have seen Peach pull up a Mr. Saturn before, and I want to know the chances of that happening.

The Bob-omb I am referencing came from a Project-M Clip I saw, so it might have only been in Melee.

Comment: I have also pulled up beam swords in Super Smash Bros Brawl on several occasions.  I wonder what all of the possible items are.

Answer (score 6):

This tip shows up at one of the loading screens on the Wii U version:

> Peach: Vegetable – Rarely, Peach will pull up a Bob-omb or Mr. Saturn. How rarely? Well, you have a 1/250 chance of a Bob-omb and a 1/166 chance of a Mr. Saturn!

I remembered seeing the tip (but forgot the numbers), then spent a good time searching for a reliable source. Eventually found it [here](http://www.ssbwiki.com/List_of_tips_(SSB4-Wii_U)).

Comment: Does it ever say the probablity of the types of faces (on the Vegatables)?

Comment: Nope. Nothing about beam swords either.

Answer (score 0):

There is a combined chance of 4/58 chance of pulling a non-veggie item.

- Beam Sword
- Bob-omb
- Mr. Saturn
- Stitch-face

Each with a chance of 1/58 being drawn.

In melee, the chances were 1/3000, so much, much lower.

Source of odds [here.](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Vegetable)

Comment: The question is about ssb4 not brawl

Comment: Grabbed wrong link. Same odds in Brawl and SSB4. Fixed to point to a SSB4 Wiki page.

Comment: I don't think we know the odds in SSB4 yet; they can't be exactly the same because Beam Swords are no longer possible.

Comment: Do you have a cite for that? I'll modify my answer if you do, but I looked online and nothing turned up indicating that beam swords were no longer possible.